# Numbers and lines underneath notes

Tags: sheet-music, clarinet

What do the numbers and lines beside them mean when under a note on clarinet sheet music[image]

Comment: A line like that typically means a continuation of some sort. For example, lines like that are used for a word sung across many notes. Here's it's not immediately clear. Some more context might help. Could you post a larger image of the music? Maybe the entire line of the excerpt?

Comment: Also, knowing the time signature would be helpful. Is it cut time (2/2) by chance? And does the time signature change on the next line?

Comment: The accel. with the lines means accelerando (accelerating) and the lines imply the notes that should be played in accelerating speed. The numbers below the notes though... They seem to imply some rhythmic information as they are aligned with the notes and beats of the bar. 1_ 2_ would imply 1 and 2 and. But it's weird because for that slow pace you'd expect half notes not quaters, So maybe that info isn't for you? The next bar has the regular 4/4 rhythm.

Comment: Please provide the source - a published song?  a study for beginners?  Is there a note on the cover page explaining anything?